# Непонятный smali

Tags: android, jar, apk, smali

Я начинающий декомпилятор андроид приложений. Появилась нужда кое-что поменять в алгоритмах работы официального приложения ВКонтакте: чтобы перед входом выполнялось сохранение введенного логина и пароля в локальную базу данных, а также замена `EditText` на `AutoCompleteTextView`, для автозаполнения данных. Дело в том, что страничек у меня несколько и не очень-то удобно каждый раз вводить разные данные для входа. Затем, чтобы данные не сохранялись по умолчанию, нужно будет добавить `CheckBox` "сохранить пароль". В результате это будет очень удобно, а главное - отличное начало в практике декомпиляции и модификации. У меня есть ноутбук на Windows и рутованный android с деодексированной прошивкой. Скачал `apktool` и ввожу команду

```
apktool d apks\vk.apk
```

Где vk.apk - нетронутый APK, в папке apks. После завершения процесса я получаю папку vk с декомпилированным содержимым. С радостью и азартом открываю ее, ищу файлы `.class` - их нет. Зато есть некая папка с файлами `.smali`. Погуглив, понимаю что до чистого java кода добраться сложно и даже, если все получится, то высока вероятность получить ошибку при обратной компиляции. Поэтому, я отказался от `dex2jar` и решил учить `smali` следующим образом:

1) В студии делаю простенькие приложения с наипростейшим java кодом активности

2) Декомпилирую его

3) Сравниваю `java` код со `smali`

Так и учусь потихоньку. Единственное, что мне непонятно, это `move-object` и всякие другие коды этого типа, а также эти `v1, v2, v3, v4, v5` и т.д. Особого внимания им не предал, поэтому решил просто, для начала создать класс враппер для работы с базой данных на java, декомпилировать его в smali и просто скопировать его в `smali/com/vkontakte/android` поменяв ссылки типа `Lcom...` на свои. Компилирую обратно:

```
apktool b vk -o vk-mod.apk
```

Где `vk` - папка для компиляции, `vk-mod.apk` - новый apk. Переношу на телефон, подписываю Zip Signer-ом, удаляю старую версию, устанавливаются мод, запускаю, вхожу в аккаунт. Так как я не добавил никакого кода для добавления записей в БД (метод insert), то база данных должна быть, но просто пустая. Запускаю Root Explorer, перехожу в `/data/data/com.vkontakte.andtoid/databases` и моей `save.bd` нету. Вообще. Проверяю, а вдруг база данных создаётся после вставки первой записи? Нет, она создаётся сразу при первом запуске, проверяю код `smali`, все верно, в чем проблема-то? Ладно, думаю дальше - может я не туда кинул `smali`? Нет, все верно. Подумал, наверно сделаю всё-таки вставку данных при нажатии на кнопку. В `smali` я полный ноль, поэтому пришлось немного подумать, чтобы найти куда рыть:

1) Ищу `xml` с этими двумя `EditText`-ами и кнопкой входа - `auth.xml`

2) Записываю имя `xml` и `id` полей логина и пароля, а также кнопки

3) Ищу идентификаторы в 16-ричном формате в `R$id.smali` и `R$layout.smali`

4) Делаю поиск с помощью Total Commander по всей папке `smali`, задав в ключевых словах сначала идентификатор `xml`, затем `id` тех самых `view`-элементов.

5) Смотрю на код `AuthActivity.smali` и туплю

Вроде, бы знакомые методы - `getText()`, `toString()`, `find iewById()`, затем передаются в лямбду логин и пароль, запускается `ProgressDialog`. Понимаю, что мне нужно "перехватить" логин и пароль при нажатии на кнопку сразу, до кода отправки их в процесс самого входа. Опять туплю. `v16, p34` и всякие `invoke-direct` мозолят глаза, написал на java код для `getWritableDatabase`, `ContentValues`, методы `put` и конечный `insert`. Тестирую - работает. Декомпилирую его, узнаю как это будет в `smali` и вставляю в `AuthActivity`, примерно на место. Не знаю никакого нормального менеджера для редактирования, поиска и ковыряния в `smali`, поэтому все выполняю в блокноте, прошу не критиковать, я не знаю как это можно делать по-другому. В итоге, на этапе компиляции `classes.dex` вылазиют ошибки :( Сдался...  Но ненадолго: на 4pda нашёл отличную тему, называется Инструкции по редактированию системных ресурсов, где профессионалы выкладывают инструкции типа "добавление кнопки сделать скриншот в шторке". Сравнивая коды, я начал получать хоть какие-то основы в `smali` кодинге, но вот никак и не пойму ничего. Народ, прошу вас, объясните мне конкретно максимально все базовые понятия о `smali`, так как в интернете я нашёл только информацию на английском, трудно и непонятно. И ещё - есть ли среда для редактирования `smali`, чтобы не ломать мозг в блокноте, без подсветки синтаксиса и всяких предупреждений об ошибках? И последнее - я правильно делаю все с `R.smali`, поиском идентификаторов? Оцените мой алгоритм, и помогите освоить `smali`. Очень надо. В будущем может создам сайт, группу в социальных сетях или даже приложение. Жду вразумительных ответов :)

Comment: По вашей теме статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/301832/

Comment: @iramm, спасибо. Но в статье недостаточно материала именно по "ковырянию" в .smali коде, мне нужен ответ с максимально понятной информацией о базовых принципах программирования на языке-ассемблере Dalvik

Comment: Почему не используешь JADX чтобы посмотреть соотвествующий java код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smali схож с Java-байт-кодом, его знание может помочь.
Но, так как в процессорах ARM-архитектуры много регистров, Google решили сэкономить и заменить долгие прогулки в память (в стек, как в JVM) на быстрые походы в регистры. Поэтому основное отличие байт-кода Dalvik от байт-кода JVM — ориентированность на регистры.

Например, `System.out.println("Hello")` в JVM-байт-коде выглядит приблизительно так:

```
getstatic System.out // PrintWriter на стеке
ldc "Hello" // PrintWriter, "Hello" — два объекта на стеке
invokevirtual PrintWriter.println(String):void // оба объекта забираются со стека
// на PrintWriter выполняется виртуальный метод с параметром "Hello"
```

В Dalvik-байт-коде:

```
sget-object v0, System.out // PrintWriter в нулевом регистре
const-string v1, "Hello" // "Hello" в первом регистре
invoke-virtual PrintWriter.println(String):void, v0, v1
// вызвать виртуальный метод println на объекте v0 с параметром v1
```

Собственно, `move-object` перекладывает объект из регистра в регистр, а все эти v0, v1 и так далее — и есть регистры (value registers).

Кроме них есть ещё parameter registers — p0, p1 и т. д.. В этих регистрах оказываются значения, переданные в метод как параметры. Если метод не статический, то в `p0` будет находиться `this`.

`invoke-direct` напоминает `invokespecial` в JVM — он вызывает не виртуальный не статический метод. Примером могут служить финальные (и/или приватные) instance-методы.

Кроме того, в smali (в отличие от .class) нет пула констант, они задаются прямо в коде (см. `fill-array-data-payload`, `const-string`). Это связано с тем, что на все классы, находящиеся в одном dex, есть только один общий пул констант — это уменьшает объём по сравнению с .class и экономит время, потраченное на интернирование строк при загрузке классов.

Официальная документация с кратким, но понятным описанием опкодов: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html

Практический пример взлома приложения:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/141522/

Плагин к IDEA / Android Studio для smali: https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/wiki/smalidea

P. S. в таких низкоуровневых вещах очень помогает знание того, как работает каждая малейшая деталь кода. Такое понимание характерно для опытного программиста. И к таким вещам можно вернуться через некоторый промежуток времени, посмотреть свежим взглядом и понять больше, чем раньше.

P. P. S. Непосредственно на тему ВКонтакте. Есть пара мыслей, готов поделиться в личку, если оставишь свои контакты (электропочту, например).